# How Do I Weight a Dataset to Match Needed Demographics in R?

Tags: r, mathematical-statistics, weighted-regression, weighted-sampling, weighted-data

If I have the [attached file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LHqDdvqnABCxM_X9hYDYtwD4HTipX4WSFHfa-mW-ys8/edit?usp=sharing) of 100 people with this dataset with the following demographics/regions:

- **Region:** Center: 12%, East: 62%, West: 26%
- **Sex:** Female: 82%, Male: 18%
- **Party:** D: 89%, R: 4%, O: 7%
- **Race:** Black: 41%, Caucasian: 56%, Hispanic: 3%

If I load that into R to create a linear regression model based off the `support` column, is there a way for me to weight those results to fit these demographics/regions?

- **Region:** Center: 14%, East: 50%, West: 36%
- **Sex:** Female: 82%, Male: 18%
- **Party:** D: 60%, R: 26%, O: 14%
- **Race:** Black: 25%, Caucasian: 72%, Hispanic: 3%

In the [same attached file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LHqDdvqnABCxM_X9hYDYtwD4HTipX4WSFHfa-mW-ys8/edit?usp=sharing), there are breakdowns of all four of these criteria in the unweighted tab (first dataset) and weighted tab (second dataset).

Also this would ideally be in R since this is where I'd create the model -- but open to doing something somewhere else too if it makes a big difference.

--

*EDIT: Original post had age as a criteria which was removed to make the example less complicated.*

Comment: This also seemed like a better fit for Cross Validated than somewhere like Stack Overflow, but please let me know if I'm mistaken and will happily move it. Thanks!

Comment: Did you run logistic or simple linear regression?

Comment: @NikTuzov      Logistic -- but also super interested to hear about how weighting these numbers would be different pending the type of regression, since I'd need to do that in both forms.

Comment: @NikTuzov      Do you know anything about this? https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcran.r-project.org%2Fweb%2Fpackages%2Fweights%2Fweights.pdf Closest I could find but I don't think I'm as well versed in R yet to read this and fully understand how it'd do what I'm asking.

Comment: What is your goal? Is it to fit the model on the first dataset, and then get the predicted values for the second dataset?

Comment: @NikTuzov      I only have one dataset of people/responses (attached in the question) -- but the weight is all off. The second part of my question is laying out what the ideal weight would be if I could fix the dataset to that criteria so I'm not over-representing Democrats, for example. And then after the weight is fixed from the first set of percentages to the second, then I was going to create a model from it. But I'm unsure as to how to fix the weight problem before I run the logistic regression. Does that make sense?

Comment: @NikTuzov      Also possible I'm thinking about it incorrectly but at this point I can't change the dataset I got back to be a representative sample, so to make it as close as possible, I was hoping I could weight the western region and Republicans, for example, heavier so that the modeling wouldn't be so off. I know it won't be perfect either, but would definitely like to avoid modeling off such a skewed sample.

Answer (score 1):

If you have only the first data set, then in order to predict the number of "Yes" responses for the second data set, more information is needed. For instance, if we looked just at Gender, then it's possible to estimate $P\{Yes | Male\}$ and $P\{Yes | Female\}$ from the first data set. Since the number of males and females in the 2nd data set is known, it's possible to use that information to predict "support". If you want to consider more factors, it becomes hard/impossible. E.g. if Region is also of interest, then for the 2nd data set you need to know the count of males and females by the region. If you want to consider all five factors, then you need to know the count of people in each of 3*2*4*3*3 cells of the 5-dimensional table that describes the 2nd dataset.

Comment: Thanks! And yes -- if I do know all the breakdowns from the first and the second dataset, is it possible to lay out how to effectively do something like this in R before running the logistic regression? I can do whatever breakdowns are necessary to make it work -- it's all the same dataset I attached in the question. The first layout of numbers is what I got back and the second set is how I'd like them weighted before creating the model. Happy to provide additional information if it helps -- but would love to know how it's done assuming I do have all the breakdowns.

Comment: This is the dataset again: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5bpg7DkSUq0VlRZNTU5VHFENVE/view -- and if a five-dimensional table is too much to do, I can extrapolate on my own if we just want to do do weights by gender and region, for example. But would love to get help since I'm stuck on the workflow in R. Can get the data, can run the model, and predict support -- but not based on the needed weights. And it's fine if doing this increases my standard error. Thanks again!

Comment: Here's actually a new link to the unweighted and weighted samples with four of the criteria above (removed age to make it less complicated): https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LHqDdvqnABCxM_X9hYDYtwD4HTipX4WSFHfa-mW-ys8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: (Hope this is my last comment on this!) But I also know my unweighted sample is missing some necessary regions, so if it's possible to still get help on doing this just on sex, party, and race, that'd be great. Thanks again!

Comment: If you know all of the breakdowns for the 2nd dataset, then you can train the model on the first dataset and use "predict" function to estimate Support for the 2nd dataset. That is, you don't have to weight anything. The general usage is shown here: http://www.theanalysisfactor.com/r-tutorial-glm1/

Comment: However, in your case it's going to be more complicated because you only have the breakdowns for the 2nd dataset, not the dataset itself. You'll have to estimate the probability of "Yes" for all factor combinations using the first dataset and "predict()" and then apply that to the corresponding combinations of the 2nd dataset.

Comment: Thanks! And right -- your second point is the right one. I have the _breakdowns_ for the "second dataset" (since it doesn't really exist). I solely have the first (and only) dataset; the "second dataset" are just the demographic/geographic breakdowns I need it to have (accepting increased error). But your `predict()` sentence is about as far as I've gotten but that's where I'm stuck. Don't know how to change the weight of the prediction so it doesn't over-inflate African American support, for example. Thanks!

Comment: Actually now that I'm thinking about it more generally -- I do have the second dataset that I could fit it to. I've done that before using things like `predict(model, newdata = newdata, type = "response")` but my problem here is that I always assumed that was incorrect because the dataset of my first sample has such skewed demographics. Is that not the case?

Comment: In your case, the difference between datasets doesn't seem to be that large. There is an interesting discussion here: http://www.analyticbridge.com/forum/topics/handling-imbalanced-data-when-building-regression-models